# Sprites appear as white boxes

Tags: android, libgdx

I have a simple LibGdx application with two sprites. One is a simple texture which is repeated to fill the background. This one works. The other is a texture which is alpha blended so the corners look darker than the center. It is stretched to cover the entire screen. For some reason, this one appears in the wrong location and is just a big white box.

Here is my code:

```
public class TestGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    boolean showingMenu;
    Texture background;
    Sprite edgeBlur;
    Texture edgeBlurTex;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        showingMenu = true;

        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        background = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("blue1.png"));
        edgeBlurTex = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("edge_blur.png"));
        edgeBlur = new Sprite(edgeBlurTex);
        edgeBlur.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        super.resize(width, height);
        edgeBlur.setSize(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        background.dispose();
        edgeBlurTex.dispose();
        super.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        batch.begin();

        drawBackground();

        batch.end();
    }

    private void drawBackground() {
        for (float x = 0; x < Gdx.graphics.getWidth(); x += background.getWidth()) {
            for (float y = 0; y < Gdx.graphics.getHeight(); y += background.getHeight()) {
                batch.draw(background, x, y);
            }
        }

        edgeBlur.draw(batch);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

I fixed it by changing the draw command to:

```
batch.draw(edgeBlurTex, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
```

**However** the if I attempt to do any drawing after drawing these textures, such as:

```
    ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();

    shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
    shapeRenderer.setColor(0, 0, 0, 1);

    float unitHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 9;
    float indent = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 20;

    shapeRenderer.rect(indent, unitHeight, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - indent * 2, unitHeight);
    shapeRenderer.rect(indent, unitHeight * 3, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - indent * 2, unitHeight);
    shapeRenderer.rect(indent, unitHeight * 5, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - indent * 2, unitHeight);
    shapeRenderer.rect(indent, unitHeight * 7, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - indent * 2, unitHeight);

    shapeRenderer.end();
```

It just stops working and goes back to drawing a white box. It seems very random, like something is seriously misconfigured with libgdx. Is there any way to debug this thing to work out what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add `enableBlending` before your blended texture draw

```
    batch.enableBlending();

    edgeBlur.draw(batch);

    batch.disableBlending();
```

you can also try to set the batch blending func by using [setBlendFunction](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html#setBlendFunction-int-int-) method after batch is created

---

update due to edit:

**the SpriteBatch should be ended when starting Shaperenderer**

Comment: ok then try to brace the Shaperenderer code with `Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);` {your_shaperenderer_code} `Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL20.GL_BLEND);`

Comment: also - is SpriteBatch ended when you are starting Shaperenderer?

Comment: Ok, so apparently ShapeRenderer has an undocumented requirement that previous sprite batches need to be ended before you start drawing? Ending the SpriteBatch fixed the problem - though it feels like LibGdx could do a little more to alert to these errors, other than drawing random white rectangles all over the screen.

Comment: totally agree - the issue seems to be connected with changing status of GL by SpriteBatch and ShapeRenderer